# Reverse CABasicAnimation on remove

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-animation, cabasicanimation

I'm using a `CABasicAnimation` instance to animate the scaling of a `UIControl` upon tap. The functionality should be that the control will scale to 0.9 and then stay there while it is still being pressed, and when the user releases his/her finger, it will enlarge back to its original size.

So far I have created the animation and it works perfectly up until the point where it will animate back to its original size. Instead of creating a separate animation to do the enlarging, I am simply removing the original animation. Is there a way of animation this removal so that it will effectively look like the control is shrinking and enlarging in response to touch?

```
- (void)shrinkView {
    CABasicAnimation *shrink = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.scale"];
    shrink.toValue = @(0.9);
    shrink.duration = 0.5;
    shrink.delegate = self;
    shrink.removedOnCompletion = NO;
    shrink.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
    [self.layer addAnimation:shrink forKey:@"shrink"];
}

- (void)enlargeView {
    [self.layer removeAnimationForKey:@"shrink"];
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    [self reduceBackgroundOpacity];
    [self shrinkView];
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
    [self increaseBackgroundOpacity];
    [self enlargeView];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're making this harder than it needs to be. The stuff about `removedOnCompletion` and `removeAnimationForKey:` is bogus. Just animate a scale transform when the touch starts and animate back to the identify transform when the touch ends.

(You don't even need to use CABasicAnimation; a simple UIView animation will do - unless you're using autolayout, in which case CABasicAnimation is better.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Problem is that this way works perfectly with user interactions. If the user decides to hold the button down for a few ms instead of just tapping and releasing, it will enlarge from its current scale. Otherwise if I use the standard `CGAffineTranform`s, it will not be able to animate from its current scale, it will go straight to 0.9 before coming back up to 1. Is there anyway around that?

Comment: The problem is that you're doing CABasicAnimation wrong. First set the value you want to change to (without animation). Then do the animation from the current value to that value. See my explanation here: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch17.html#_using_a_cabasicanimation